# error on R code (model.matrix.default(mt,mf,contrast)

Tags: r, plot

I know zero, zip, nothing about R. I'm following [this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4975/graph-sql-server-database-growth-using-r-and-powershell/#comments) to get an image with predicted database growth. The actual R code execution is this one:

```
x <- data[,2];
qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = T);
caps <- quantile(x, probs=c(.05, .95), na.rm = T);
H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = T);
x[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- caps[1];
x[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- caps[2];
data[,2] <- x;
jpeg(filename=\"$graphicPath$graphicName\");
plot(data, type=\"l\", las=1, col=\"green\", xlim=c(0, 90), ylim=c(650, 5750));
model <- lm(Size ~ Date, data);
abline(model, col=\"blue\");
x <- 90;
y <- round(predict(model, data.frame(Date=c(x))));
points(x, y);
text(x, y, y, pos=3);
dev.off();
```

But it fails with the following error:

> Error in model.matri.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :

Comment: after which line do you get the error - is it the full error? Can you share a small example of `data` so we can run your code - you can do this by adding the results of `dput(data[1:10, c("Size", "Date")])` to your question (assuming data[,2] == data[,  "Date"]). Thanks

Comment: The full code is a one liner, so I don't get an exact line error, I'm following a tutorial on the provided link on the question.

Comment: if you step through the code, running it line by line, you would see which throws the error - but it is likely the `lm` call. It suggests something is not quite right in your data, so really need to see an example of your data to suggest something further.  If you could add a small example of the data to your question it would be very helpful (`dput(data[1:10, c("Size", "Date")])`), otherwise use `str(data)` to see if the variable class is what you expect.

Comment: agree with user20650, without a few lines of data it is hard to give you an answer.

Comment: As commented, I'm following a tutorial, all the details are there. Data is grabbed from a tsql query with data related to databases backup sizes. Nevertheless, I managed to find the error, data set was empty due to an incorrect statement on the tsql, corrected, is working now.